# IntelliJ IDEA doesn't load Lift libraries from a SBT project

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, lift, sbt

I've created a blank project via `sbt` using the most basic guide, specifically:

```
> cd xyz
> sbt # here we create a new project w/ Scala 2.8.1
> *lift is org.lifty lifty 1.6.1
> lift create project-blank
```

however when I open the project in IntelliJ, it doesn't correctly recognize .jars downloaded via sbt. All imports are red

[image: red imports]

and when I go to project settings (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>) in Libraries section, they are all greyed out.

[image: greyed out libraries]

Apart from that, the project sources are correctly recognized as Scala project with a Web facet

[image: project structure]

**Did I forget to configure something? I've already tried to create a project via maven using  [this guide](http://www.assembla.com/spaces/liftweb/wiki/Using_IntelliJ_IDEA_to_develop_Lift_applications), but I'd very much prefer to use SBT instead of maven.**

Comment: Do you have these libraries added to the module dependencies? See http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/configuring-module-dependencies-and-libraries.html.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `sbt-idea` to create the IntelliJ project structure. Re-run this each time you change the project structure or the library dependencies in your SBT build definition.

Instructions: [SBT 0.10.x 0.11.x](https://github.com/mpeltonen/sbt-idea), [SBT 0.7.x](https://github.com/mpeltonen/sbt-idea/tree/sbt-0.7)

Comment: with SBT 0.12.x you should use" `gen-idea`